# SQL to find first non-numeric character in a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string, parsing

I inherited a table with identifiers in a format [nonnumericprefix][number].  For example (ABC123; R2D2456778; etc).  I was wondering if there was a good way to split this in SQL into two fields, the largest integer formed from the right side, and the prefix, for example (ABC, 123; R2D, 2456778; etc).  I know I can do this with a cursor, C# code, etc - and I will if I have to - but I don't run into things I cannot do fast and easily in SQL very often, so I thought I'd post it here.

Comment: BTW - I just realized I asked my topic as the "to find first non-numeric character" and gave an example asking to find the last non-numeric.  Reversing a string is trivial, so this doesn't change the nature of the question.

Comment: Better edit the question as oppose to clarify it with comment.

Comment: Did not know about PATINDEX, this is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Reverse the string
2. Use PATINDEX to find the first occurrence of a non numeric field
3. Use the LEFT function to return the numeric portion of the string

Code sample

```
DECLARE @myString varchar(100);
DECLARE @largestInt int;

SET @myString = 'R2D2456778'

SET @mystring = REVERSE(@myString);
SET @largestInt = LEFT(@myString, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', @myString) - 1)

PRINT ( CONVERT(varchar(100), @largestInt) )
```

Comment: Nice solution, but to get the original int part of myString, you'll need to reverse largestInt.

Comment: This will fail with anything other thatn a-z, try R2D245.6778

Answer (score 18):

You can use `PATINDEX` with a pattern like `'%[^0123456789]%'` or `'%[^0-9]%'` to find the position of the first non-numeric character

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ABC123'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'R2D2456778'

SELECT  *,
        LEFT(Val,LEN(Val) - (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',REVERSE(Val)) - 1)),
        RIGHT(Val,(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',REVERSE(Val)) - 1))      
FROM    @Table
```

Comment: +1 looks good, would benefit from a cast to `int` on third column.

Comment: Possibly not an issue for the OP, but I had a problem with `[^0-9]` matching alt codes (like ¼, etc.) and then failing the cast to an integer. Using `[^0123456789]` instead, for some reason, fixed the issue.