# Concatenate & Trim String

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me, I have a problem regarding on how can I get the below result of data. refer to below sample data. So the logic for this is first I want delete the letters before the number and if i get that same thing goes on , I will delete the numbers before the letter so I can get my desired result.

Table:

```
SALV3000640PIX32BLU
SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY
TP3000620PIXL128BLK
```

Desired Output:

```
PIX32BLU
A9CARBONGRY
PIXL128BLK
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the split?

Comment: What problem was that? What do you actually want to do? Chop off everything before the first letter after a number? Sample data is all well and good, but it doesn't specifically explain what you want, nor does it necessarily reflect all the real data you might put into the queries people suggest. You should explain in as much depth as possible so that people can provide relevant answers. This is too unclear.

Comment: Yes Exactly... @underscore_d

Comment: Your right, I actually want to chop this to get the desired result. I want to delete first the letters before the number and if I get that then I want to delete now the numbers before the letter so I can get my desired result. but I don't know ho or I don't have idea.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that info and anything else that could help readers understand and answer it adequately.

Comment: @underscore_d so you understand now on what iam supposed to do?

Comment: What if your string starts with a number? or it's all numbers or all letters? What if your string is `asdf5345`? should that return an empty string?

Comment: @ZoharPeled it will not start with a number. all of my data starts with letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a combination of the `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX` Functions

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(fielda,PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',fielda),99),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(fielda,PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',fielda),99)),99) AS youroutput
FROM yourtable
```

Input

yourtable

```
fielda
SALV3000640PIX32BLU
SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY
TP3000620PIXL128BLK
```

Output

```
youroutput
PIX32BLU
A9CARBONGRY
PIXL128BLK
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5722b6/29/0

Comment: This is great! CHEERS! :)

Comment: I have a question with this, for what is `PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',fielda),99)` what is 99?

Comment: 99 is the length of the string they return, i just used 99 as it was longer that anything you needed in your examples but your actual data may be longer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',FieldName)
```

which will give you the position of the first number, then trim off any letters before this using SUBSTRING or other string functions.  (You need to trim away the first letters before continuing with the next step because unlike CHARINDEX there is no starting point parameter in the PATINDEX function).

Then on the remaining string use

```
PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',FieldName)
```

to find the position of the first letter in the remaining string.  Now trim off the numbers in front using SUBSTRING etc.

You may find this other solution helpful

[SQL to find first non-numeric character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110559/sql-to-find-first-non-numeric-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you

```
;With cte (Data)
AS
(
SELECT 'SALV3000640PIX32BLU'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SALV3334470B9CARBONGRY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SALV3334470D9CARBONGRY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'TP3000620PIXL128BLK'   
)
SELECT * , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PIX',Data)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX('PIX',Data),LEN(Data)) 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('A9C',Data)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX('A9C',Data),LEN(Data))
                ELSE NULL END AS DesiredResult FROM cte
```

Result

```
Data                    DesiredResult
-------------------------------------
SALV3000640PIX32BLU     PIX32BLU
SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY  A9CARBONGRY
SALV3334470A9CARBONGRY  A9CARBONGRY
SALV3334470B9CARBONGRY  NULL
SALV3334470D9CARBONGRY  NULL
TP3000620PIXL128BLK     PIXL128BLK
```

Comment: On what basis did you decide that those new rows you added should return `null`? If the OP hasn't provided enough info to answer, it's probably not worth making up new criteria so that you can answer.

Comment: i just added the sample query  just to get an idea to figure out his requirement ,i didn't said that is exact result what he expects